# Expecting anything as parameter to mock using EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, mocking, easymock

Using EasyMock I want to be able to say that I expect a specific method called on my mock, but I do not care about the parameter which are used to call the mock.

```
SomeInterface mock = EasyMock.createMock(SomeInterface.class);
mock.send(/*anything*/);
replay(mock);

/* Perform actions that will eventually invoke mock */

verify(mock);
```

Is this possible, and how?

Additionally if I want to accept any object that derives from a specific base class, how do I specify that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To accept any object as parameter:

```
mock.send(anyObject());
```

(You may need to cast the expression to the desired type.)

In addition, to accept any object of a specific type, use:

```
mock.send(isA(SomeObject.class));
```

Comment: What is the difference between anyObject(clazz.class) and isA(clazz.class) ?

Comment: @ChandraMohan as far as I can see, there is no `anyObject(clazz.class)`, only `anyObject()`, which returns an instance of `Object`, and `isA(clazz.class)` returns an instance of type `clazz`, which is exactly the difference between them.

Comment: PS: the `anyObject()` is a static method from EasyMock. So, you can use `EasyMock.anyObject()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Additionally if I want to accept any object that derives from a
>   specific base class, how do I specify that?

```
mock.send(anyObject(Myclass.class));
```

Comment: No! This does not work! This is the first I tried, however it will verify with success even if the actual object does not derive from `Myclass`. This notation is only to avoid having to cast the result from `anyObject()` to what `mock.send()` expects. It does *not* verify that the method is called with a class that derives from `Myclass`. You have to use `isA()` as shown in Péter Töröks answers.

Comment: Interesting.
Thanks for sharing :)